# Run PHP from a script

Tags: php, bash

I am trying to run the following script on Unix, and I am not able to.

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php
    include(`abc.php`);
```

It gives me,

```
: No such file or directory
bash: doctrine: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `('
bash: doctrine: line 3: `echo include(`abc.php`);'
```

How do I fix this problem?

Comment: Did you confirm location of php with `which php`?  Also, you should be using single quotes `'` instead of back-ticks (`)in your include

Comment: if I try to run - php abc.php it wruns the php file. That means i guess the php location is fine

Comment: The quotes are your problem. Backticks cause their content to be passed to a shell. You want to use double or single quotes instead, as @AndrewCoder has already mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

You're using the wrong quotes. Correct example:

```
<?php
    include('abc.php');
```